# Import specific text from a file to list in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a text file which looks like:

```
line A
line B
line C
line D

objective
8.5770822e+000
3762931e+000
0996787e+000
0070925e+000
0003053e+000
9999994e+000

line E
line F
line G
```

I want to import numbers under the word "objective" into a Python list.

Challenges:
The number of lines (with numbers) under the line with "objective" need not be the same. It varies from file to file. I am trying to develop a generic code. So the stop condition must be based on a blank line under the numbers.

My idea:
I was able to access the line "objective" with the code `if line.startswith("objective")`
But to access the lines below until you find a blank line seems challenging.

Can you please help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I used the command if line.startswith("objective") to access that specific line. I can add that line to a list using list.append(line).  The idea is to access all the lines under "objective", until you find a blank line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my proposition:

- Read the file into a list
- save each lines from "Objective" to the last line into a new list `numbers`
- take away the `0th` elements and all the elements from the first empty `''` elements to the end.

What will be left are the numbers you need.

Here is my implem

```py
def main():
    #read file 
    g = open(r"test.txt")
    # read all lines
    lst= g.readlines();
    numbers = []
    # at the beginning no number is found

    # flag to track if we shall save or not in the list
    start_saving = False
    # a loop to save all from objective to the end
    for l in lst:
       l=l.strip("\n")
       if ("objective" in l):
            start_saving= True
       if (start_saving):
            numbers.append(l)

    # here we  obtain an array containing all elements from Objective to the end
    # ['objective', '8.5770822e+000', '3762931e+000', '0996787e+000', '0070925e+000', '0003053e+000', '9999994e+000', '', 'line E', 'line F', 'line G']
    # i will now strip away all elements of index 0 ("Objective") and from the first empty index (the first line containing nothing)
    # only keep elements from 1st to the first element not empty
    numbers = numbers[1:numbers.index('')]
    print numbers
    # display : ['8.5770822e+000', '3762931e+000', '0996787e+000', '0070925e+000', '0003053e+000', '9999994e+000']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This outputs:

```sh
['8.5770822e+000', '3762931e+000', '0996787e+000', '0070925e+000', '0003053e+000', '9999994e+000']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to know an idea for one more case. Some lines may have more than one number, separated by a space. In that case, what modification would you make to your code?

Comment: I will look and make you a proposition. Could you provide an example of txt file and the corresponding output in order to have the same test basis

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I am not sure how to share a text file with you.

Comment: No worries, I think I understand what you want. I will look and propose it a little later this day

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and support. Here I have the format and the expected results
pastebin.pl/view/5b2394e9

In fact, I simplified the text I am working with, for easy communication.  I am sharing the original text as well
https://pastebin.pl/view/668a3bee

Comment: You may add this to the second problem. Ifyou do not understand, please open another question with the problem and I will post you a solution. 

 I do not have access to pastebin from where I am .

```
    first=[]
    second=[]
    for string in numbers:
        array = string.split(" ")
        first.append(array[0])
        second.append(array[1])
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224688/discussion-between-pat-andria-and-wilson-mendes).

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to have a flag indicating whether or not the word "objective" has been seen.

Something like this:

```
res = []
objective_seen = False
with open(filename) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if objective_seen:
            if line:
                res.append(line)
            else:  # blank line
                break
        else:  # objective not yet seen
            if line.startswith('objective'):
                objective_seen = True
```

Another way would be to have two loops, one to process the file up to "objective", the other to process the rest:

```
res = []
with open(filename) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith('objective'):
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError('No "objective" section in file')

    for line in fh:
        if line:
            res.append(line)
        else:
            break
```